# Spring Boot 3.0 ClassLoader problem when using setStatusCode on ServerHttpResponse

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hi i was try to migrate from spring boot 2.7.X to spring boot 3.0.X

I find really weird application behaviour. In one class i do sth like this

```
public class ExampleFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, @NonNull WebFilterChain chain) {
        var response = exchange.getResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
        return chain.filter(exchange);

    }
}
```

From spring 6.0 application stop building when this setStatusCode method is in class.

exception look like this

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'allowedMethodsFilter': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [tmp.AllowedMethodsFilter] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@7eda2dbb]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:64)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:745)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:420)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:164)
    at tmp.ExampleApp.main(ExampleApp.java:21)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [tmp.AllowedMethodsFilter] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@7eda2dbb]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:267)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/HttpStatusCode
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2504)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.http.HttpStatusCode
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

It seems that every place that was using set/get response (ServerHttpResponse) stop working

Comment: This generally stems from the fact that you are mixing up incompatible libraries, generally coming from managing the wrong dependencies or trying to outsmart the Sprig Boot Starters. Please add your build file with dependencies.